# How to estimate web app usage of RAM and CPU?

Tags: web-applications, migration, cloud, wamp, ram

So I am facing the following scenario:
My web app, having separate backend as a windows service and frontend server hosted on WAMP. Also I have mysql database.

Now we want to move the solution to a cloud platform.

The issue is, I need to estimate how many CPU and GB RAM we need for the app.

Could someone give me some guidance on how to do that?